# Why are buddy classes used for validation?

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

I am curious as to why data validation is done using buddy classes. Consider the following example, where `MyEntity` is a Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities entity, and the class below is a partial class enhancing the entity.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntity.MyEntityMetadata))]
public partial class MyEntity
{
    private class MyEntityMetadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The title is required.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why is the design so? When they designed DataAnnotations, why was this "buddy pattern" selected? Why not place the attributes directly in the entity?

Comment: My understanding is it allows you to extend the characteristics outside of the designer. You'd hate adjusting meta attributes only to have your next designer update wipe them all out.

Comment: Single Responsibility Principal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is practical - in linq-to-sql and linq-to-entities, the code representing the classes regenerated every time the object model is updated.  In order for the annotations not to be overwritten when this happens, they need to be in a separate "buddy" class.

If you're using Data Annotations in a different context - say for a view model - then they can go on the original class itself.

Comment: I was unaware that the attributes could be placed on the data class directly, such as directly in the View Model. Answer marked for the additional detail. Thanks.

Comment: "buddy pattern" - not a "pattern", is just to avoid nastiness. never a great design from MS teams.

Answer (score 5):

I assume this prevents generated entities from overwriting custom Meta Data information.