# Application does not recognize WCF service client when reuse types in referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that uses an external assembly for it's DTOs. The consumer of the service also has a reference to this external assembly. The plan is to use these entities to pass information between the service and the consumer. I have done this multiple times with other services without a problem.

In this case, it is not working. Intellisense recognizes classes that reside in the WCF service (ie: `CreateEventRequest`), but does not display the standard `TrackingServiceClient`, meaning there is no way to instantiate the service.

If I uncheck "Reuse types in referenced assemblies", everything works as expected. Although, obviously, I would like to reuse the DTO assembly.

**The DTO**

```
[DataContract]
public class SiteTrackingEvent : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    #region Enums

    [DataContract]
    /// <summary>
    /// The different types of action categories that a user can perform
    /// </summary>
    public enum EventTypes
    {
        [EnumMember]
        None = 0,
        [EnumMember]
        Registrant = 1,
        [EnumMember]
        OnlineRequest = 2,
        [EnumMember]
        VTRequest = 3,
        [EnumMember]
        Download = 4,
        [EnumMember]
        ITRequest = 5
    }

    #endregion //Enums

    #region Properties
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public EventTypes EventType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string EventTypeDescription { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string PolicyOwnerSsnTin { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string PolicyOwnerName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string SourcePath { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string SourceNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public string SaidPrimary { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public string OfficeCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 10)]
    public string BrokerDealerCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 11)]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    #endregion //Properties

    #region IExtensibleDataObject

    private ExtensionDataObject extensionDataObject_value;

    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return extensionDataObject_value;
        }
        set
        {
            extensionDataObject_value = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion //IExtensibleDataObject

}
```

**The Service Interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITrackingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void CreateEvent(ITrackingServiceContracts.CreateEventRequest trackingEvent);
}

namespace ITrackingServiceContracts
{
    [DataContract]
    public class CreateEventRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        [Required]
        public SiteTrackingEvent TrackingEvent { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**The implementation of the service**

```
public class TrackingService : ITrackingService
{

    public void CreateEvent(CreateEventRequest trackingEvent)
    {
        Validate(trackingEvent);
        //DO WORK HERE
    }

    public void Validate(CreateEventRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
            throw new FaultException("Request object is null.");

        List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(request, new ValidationContext(request, null, null), results, true))
        {
            throw new FaultException(String.Format("The request object is not valid: {0}.", String.Concat(results.Select(r => r.ErrorMessage))));
        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody see what I am missing/doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

As per @ErikFunkenbusch request, here are the relevant parts of the generated reference.cs files.

When "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" ***is not*** checked (the version that is working as expected):

```
public partial class TrackingServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ServiceTester.UsageTracking.TrackingService.ITrackingService>, ServiceTester.UsageTracking.TrackingService.ITrackingService {

    public TrackingServiceClient() {
    }

    public TrackingServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public TrackingServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public TrackingServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public TrackingServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public void CreateEvent(ServiceTester.UsageTracking.TrackingService.CreateEventRequest mlaEvent) {
        base.Channel.CreateEvent(mlaEvent);
    }
}
```

When "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" ***is*** checked (the version that is not working as expected). Note: This is the entire generated file. It's fairly obvious it is not generating correctly:

```
namespace ServiceTester.UsageTracking.TrackingService2 {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CreateEventRequest", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.UsageTracking.ServiceInterfaces." +
        "ITrackingServiceContracts")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class CreateEventRequest {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in your reference.cs file to see what the class is named?  You need to make sure Show All Files is turned on in the Solution Explorer

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Which class are you referring to?

Comment: Your client class.  One was generated, you just don't know what the name is.  Look in the reference.cs file, looking for a class that derives from ClientBase.

Comment: Where is IServiceContracts coming from?  I don't see that in you code...  Could that be causing an error, and thus aborting generation?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: My apologies, I typed that incorrectly. In any case, that line in the reference.cs file is identical in both service references (the one that works and the one that doesn't)

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be with the CreateEventRequest class.  I notice you have an Order parameter, which is pointless since you only have one member.  I'm also confused about why you have a Required attribute.  This could be confusing svcutil.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Wow. Removing the [Required] attribute did it! I have it in there so I can use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to validate the `CreateEventRequest` object and return a detailed validation error message back to the consumer of the service. Obviously, I will now remove it and do manual validation. Do you have any idea why it would cause svcutil to error? Also, would you like to post that as an answer so you receive credit? Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'm curious, did you have to remove it from PolicyNumber in SiteTrackingEvent as well?

Comment: No I did not need to remove it from `SiteTrackingEvent`. Since I am now able to reuse referenced assemblies (namely the DTO assembly), it is not part of the WSDL anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `[Required]` on a DataContract confuses SvcUtil when it generates reusable types.  Could be a bug, or it could just be unsupported.

I would not suggest using your WCF DTO's in your view directly, and use View Models instead.  Alternatively, use Buddy Classes.

[Why are buddy classes used for validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109785/why-are-buddy-classes-used-for-validation)

Comment: Just as a side note, I am not using the DTO in a view. I was implementing the `[Required]` attribute to validate the DTO when it is sent *back* to the service.

Comment: @ShaiCohen - Ahh.. in that case, I wouldn't use your EF entities directly as WCF DTO's either (assuming that's what you mean).  Either way, a DTO should be translated from an entity or model.

Comment: I'm not using EF. Just POCOs. In that case, would you recommend creating DTOs *in addition* to the POCOs? If yes, any link you can provide discussing this would be most appreciated.

Comment: @ShaiCohen - So you're writing custom reflection code to look for your required attribute?  Or using some other library?  You might want to consider using a custom behavior to do validation instead.  A DTO is typically used strictly for data transfer, and thus is serioualized back and forth.. If you use it as-is then fine.. but if you start hanging other stuff on it, it's time to think about translating it to a different model.  At that point, you're violating the single responsibility principle.